# PDA: Symbol in first half

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, automata

How do I construct a PDA where:

$L = \{w \in \{0, 1\} ∗ : |w| \text{ is even and } w \text{ contains at least one 1-Symbol in the first Half}\}$

To me it seems impossible to know when I reached the midpoint.

Comment: Parallelly, try also the pumping lemma.

Comment: The assignment doesn't say that the PDA needs to be deterministic.

Comment: ...although a DPDA does exist, too.

Comment: Maybe it helps to reformulate the set definition. Equivalently we could say: $|w|$ is even, $w$ contains at least one 1-symbol, and the first 1-symbol that occurs is in the first half of $w$.

Comment: figured it out yesterday by myself, but @PeterLeupold reformulation really helps a lot. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is my solution:
[image: PDA]

I just stack 1s until I find the first 1-Symbol, then I pop them to see if the first 1 was in the first or second half and then I just make sure that the word is even.